# Is it possible to make an attribute configuration dependent on another attribute in Moo?

Tags: perl, moo

I have read various tutorials and the [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) documentation but I cannot find anything that describes what I want to do.

What I want to do is something like the following:

```
has 'status' => (
  is  => 'ro',
  isa => Enum[qw(pending waiting completed)],
);

has 'someother' => (
  is       => is_status() eq 'waiting'   ? 'ro' : 'rw',
  required => is_status() eq 'completed' ? 1    : 0,
  isa      => Str,
  lazy     => 1,
);
```

If I'm just way off base with this idea, how would I go about making an attribute 'ro' or 'rw' and required or not, depending on the value of another attribute?

Note, the Enum is from [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::Tiny::Enum).

Comment: The short answer is "no", because attribute configuration is "static" (i.e. applies to the whole class), independent of the values of a particular object.

Comment: So, I would probably have to override the setter method for the attribute and handle the check to determine whether or not the value can be modified or not. But I don't see how I can handle the required part ...

Comment: use a getter that determines whether it is completed?

Comment: If the caller never tries to access the attribute how would I force the call to that attributes getter?

Comment: As I'm rereading the moo docs, it occurs to me that perhaps I could use BUILDARGS to add an attribute dynamically ... or would this be an abomination?

Comment: Nope ... Constructor for $package has been inlined and cannot be updated ... hmmm perhaps I could generate a package on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself why you want to do this. You are dealing with objects. Those are data that has a set of logic applied to them. That logic is described in the class, and the object is an instance of data that has the class's logic applied.

If there is a property (which is data) that can have two different logics applied to it, is it still of the same class? After all, whether a property is changeable is a very distinct rule.

So you really have two different classes. One where the `someother` property is read-only, and one where it is changeable.

In Moo (and Moose) there are several ways to build that.

- implement Foo::Static and Foo::Dynamic (or Changeable or Whatever) where  both are subclasses of Foo and only the one property changes
- implement Foo and implement a subclass
- implement Foo and a role that changes the behaviour of `someother`, and apply it in the constructor. [Moo::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo::Role) inherits that from [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny#apply_roles_to_object).

Here is an example of the approach that uses roles.

```
package Foo;
use Moo;
use Role::Tiny ();

has 'status' => ( is => 'ro', );

has 'someother' => (
    is      => 'ro',
    lazy    => 1,
);


sub BUILD {
  my ( $self) = @_;

  Role::Tiny->apply_roles_to_object($self, 'Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic')
    if $self->status eq 'foo';
}

package Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic;
use Moo::Role;

has '+someother' => ( is => 'rw', required => 1 );

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

# ...
```

First we'll create an object that has a dynamic `someother`.

```
my $foo = Foo->new( status => 'foo', someother => 'foo' );
p $foo;
$foo->someother('asdf');
print $foo->someother;

__END__
Foo__WITH__Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic  {
    Parents       Role::Tiny::_COMPOSABLE::Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic, Foo
    Linear @ISA   Foo__WITH__Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic, Role::Tiny::_COMPOSABLE::Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic, Role::Tiny::_COMPOSABLE::Foo::Role::Someother::Dynamic::_BASE, Foo, Moo::Object
    public methods (0)
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        someother   "foo",
        status      "foo"
    }
}
asdf
```

As you can see, that works. Now let's make a static one.

```
my $bar = Foo->new( status => 'bar', someother => 'bar' );
p $bar;
$bar->someother('asdf');

__END__
Foo  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (4) : BUILD, new, someother, status
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        someother   "bar",
        status      "bar"
    }
}
Usage: Foo::someother(self) at /home/julien/code/scratch.pl line 327.
```

Ooops. A warning. Not a nice 'read-only' exception like in Moose, but I guess this is as good as it gets.

However, this will not help with the `required` attribute. You can create a `Foo->new( status => 'foo' )` without `someother` and it will still come out ok.

So you might want to settle for the subclass approach or use a role and build a [factory class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Thank you. This gives me another avenue to explore.